# RequiredFieldValidator for dropdown is not working with validation group

Tags: asp.net

I have two dropdowns inside a tabpanel.

For some reason my first dropdowns required field validator is not working and not displaying an error message in the validation summary. I checked Initial value 2, 3 times .. and 0 is the correct value for it. Its simply posted data to server if i set index zero which is initial value is 0.

However, my second dropdown validator is working.
Both got the same validation group on button.

```
<div class="Form_Input_Bigbg" id="divManagerRating" runat="server">
    <div class="Form_Label_Editor">
        <asp:Label ID="lblM`enter code here`anagerComment" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <%--Manager Comment--%>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <div id="rating8" runat="server">
        <div class="Form_Input_Big">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlManagerRating" Width="200px" runat="server" CssClass="Form_InputField">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class="error_Text_alert">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator24" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlManagerRating"
                ErrorMessage="Rating for Manager Comment required." Text="*" ForeColor="Red"
                InitialValue="0" ValidationGroup="PublishMid"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="Form_Input_Bigbg" id="divMidRecommendedRating" runat="server">
    <div class="Form_Label_Editor">
        <asp:Label ID="lblMidYearPerformanceRatingAndExplanation" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <%--Mid year performance rating & explanation--%>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
    <div id="divMidYearPerformanceRatingAndExplanationRating" runat="server">
        <div class="Form_Input_Big">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="drpMidRecommendedRating" Width="200px" runat="server" CssClass="Form_InputField">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </div>
        <div class="error_Text_alert">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="drpMidRecommendedRating"
                ErrorMessage="Rating for Mid year performance rating & explanation required."
                Text="*" ForeColor="Red" InitialValue="0" ValidationGroup="PublishMid"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="divBtnPublish" runat="server">
     <asp:Button ID="btnFinish" runat="server" CssClass="BtnRegular_Container"
         Text="Publish" OnClick="btnFinish_Click"
         OnClientClick="SetCheck()" ValidationGroup="PublishMid" />
</div>
```